# Setting up CCMenu for Cocos2d

Tags: game-design, cocos2d-iphone

I am very new to Cocos2d programming and was thinking to build up my first app. I learnt some basics related to CCMenu and CCMenuItems. But I was wondering whether I could provide animations in such a way that every CCMenuItem would animate first and then appear in the CCMenu. Will that be possible in Cocos2d? Can I get some tutorials or samples regarding this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there are two ways to implement that, the first one which is easier is to create an Object, then using CCAnimate and CCSequence classes, first animate an image and then convert it into an image.

the harder way which will result in cleaner code (I suggest this one) is to create a class which inherits normal CCMenuItems class. and change it's constructor to start an Animation instead of immediately being clickable.